# French locale is breaking button function

Tags: javascript, django, string, django-templates

**The problem**

Buttons are not functioning properly if a user is viewing the site in French locale.

**Background Info**

I am using `{% trans %}` tag to translate button text directly in my Django template. Inside of my script tags, I am also using `{% trans %}` tags to add translation after a button action is triggered (onclick): `let show_correction = '{% trans "Show native corrections" %}';`.

In French locale it becomes: `let show_correction='Afficher les corrections d'autres locuteurs natifs';`. I  think the issue is happening specifically in `d'autres`.

**My Guess**

Maybe the function is terminating earlier because of the apostrophe?

---

How in the world can I fix this?

Comment: so have the translation code have escaped quotes?

Comment: @epascarello Posted a working solution into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n

Basic usage:

```
let foo = gettext("Your string to be translated");
```